# List to csv- python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list with this format:

```py
lista_d = [
    ('1', '2', 1.393063105981541),
    ('1', '6', 1.450829019495749),
    ('1', '16', 1.4508291645112752),
    ('2', '1', 1.393063105981541),
    ('2', '3', 1.4508290090832596),
    ('2', '15', 1.4508291577448584),
    ('3', '2', 1.4508290090832596), 
    ('3', '4', 1.3930630800761916)
]
```

I need to convert this list to csv with tree columns for example

```
1       2      1.393063105981541
```

With all items in list.

I tried with this but but everything is in the first column

```py
with open('dist.csv','w') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    for i in lista_d:
        write.writerow(i)
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the delimiter to the [`csv writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

```
with open('dist.csv','w') as f:
    # you can change the delimiter in the csv
    # '\t' mean tabs
    write= csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    for i in lista_d:
        write.writerow(i)
```

dist.csv:

```
1   2   1.393063105981541
1   6   1.450829019495749
1   16  1.4508291645112752
2   1   1.393063105981541
2   3   1.4508290090832596
2   15  1.4508291577448584
3   2   1.4508290090832596
3   4   1.3930630800761916
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a delimiter when invoking `csv.writer` should solve the issue.

```
with open('dist.csv','w') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for i in lista_d:
        write.writerow(i)
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_